# LaTeX compiler giving "Illegal seek" error

Tags: compiling, compilation-error

I have TexStudio installed, whenever I try to compile the .tex file, the compiler runs for a bit, then I get the abovementioned error. This happens in TexStudio, as well as in Terminal using pdflatex. Any clues? I'm using Pop!_Os 20.04

The following is the pdflatex output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)

restricted \write18 enabled.

entering extended mode

(./tables.tex

LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2

L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls

Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty

For additional information on amsmath, use the \?' option.`

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)

(./tables.aux) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}pdflatex: tables: Illegal seek
```

Comment: that's not really a tex error but an error in the engine compilation or filesystem, or .do you get it with any file or just specific ones, if just some files, can you post a small example?

Comment: I get the error with any file, it started after upgrading Pop_os to 20.04. On Pop_os 19.10 it was working fine.

Comment: I guess you'll need to contact the debian tex maintainers and ask there, it's a system level file access error so not something we can really address here (unless you get lucky and someone recognises the issue)

Comment: I got lucky, by continuously trying new things. I'm mounting OneDrive using Rclone, and the file that I was trying to compile was saved in OneDrive. When I moved it to local storage, all was fine. So I still don't know how to resolve the error, but I found a feasible workaround. Thanks you for taking the time to ready my question Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to compile in OneDrive mounted with rclone.
The problem disappeared when I implemented a solution to make Libre Office work with rclone as suggested here https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/2906#issuecomment-574741176.

The solution is to add a flag when mounting the cloud storage

`rclone mount remote:path_to_remote path_to_local_folder --vfs-cache-mode writes`

This is also mentioned in the limitation of the mount option for rclone
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/rclone.1.html

Comment: Could you please explain your answer better, with a full code and functional with a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry...not really an expert, I just wanted to share a solution that worked for me.

Comment: I am not an expert too but your modified answer is certainly better than the previous one because it is detailed. My best regards.